# CMD can't run a exe without .exe

Tags: cmd, path

I've been trying to get mingw64 to run on my laptop. I've realized my cmd can't run gcc or g++, but can run gcc.exe and g++.exe. Any ways to fix cmd to run executables without .exe?

Comment: Please define "can't run".

Comment: Not run but rather can't find. When I run gcc --version. It will say 'gcc is not recognized as an internal or external command.' But when I run gcc.exe --version, it runs fine.

Comment: Make sure your PATHEXT variable is set correctly: https://www.nextofwindows.com/what-is-pathext-environment-variable-in-windows

Comment: Wow thank, something so simple. Turn out for some reason, I must have made a pathext variable .PY.